# Start tag p seen in table?

Tags: css, html, css-tables

In HTML5 I have created table id="sponstable in div id="sponsorship" using p in some instances to get the desired look. CSS does not validate and tells me "Start tag p seen in table."  I have attempted to edit but each method I try does not render the look I need.

Here is what it looks like:

```
&nbsp;</p> <p> 
<b> <u><font face="Arial" color="#937200" size="4">Bronze- $75 annually</font></u></b></p>
<p> <b> <font face="Arial">* Sponsor Page listing in our Meet Programs.</font></b></p>
<p> &nbsp;</p>
<p> <b> <u><font face="Arial" color="#c0c0c0" size="4">Silver - $250 (initially) $150 (annually)</font></u></b></p>
```

This is exactly what I want it to look like: http://jsfiddle.net/awb3k2Ls

Just need it to validate CSS with the W3C validator. Anything?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your code does not include the `table` or `div` you are referring to. Can you please add that?

Comment: See my answer below and give it a try. Let me know if that works

Answer (score 3):

Your error refers to invalid HTML, not invalid CSS. `<p>` elements should not be in a `<table>` element and since you are not using any `table` elements in your markup, such as `<tbody>` and `<tr>`, you can just replace the `<table id="sponstable">` with `<div id="sponstable">`.

Give that a try.

Comment: awesome! I am not sure why I did it that way but finally got it cleaned up. THANKS!